# Use dashes in URL with Symfony 1.4

Tags: routes, symfony1, symfony-1.4, separator

I'm currently trying to uses dashes as segment separators in URL with Symfony 1.4.18, and I have some troubles to make it work.

Here is my route:

```
franchise:
    url:          /number-:page-:slug
    param:        { module: store, action: franchise, page: 1 }
    options:      { suffix: .html, segment_separators: [ /,- ] }
    requirements:
        page: \d+
```

As you can see, the pattern is very simple I define a constant "number" followed by a dash and a variable :page which is only a number. It is followed by a dash and a slug (the slug can contains alphanumeric values and dashes too).

The URL is correctly generated by the method url_for but when I try to access it, I have the usual error:

> Empty module and/or action after parsing the URL...

I tried to replace the dash between :page and :slug by the plus sign (and adding it to the segment_separators) but it did not work neither.

I don't know what to do anymore? Does anyone already had this kind of trouble?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is your `slug` has some dashes, so Symfony can't determine where is the separator between `page` and `slug`.

If you add a requirement to `slug`, to explicitly tells Symfony that slug can contain dashes, it will works.

```
franchise:
  url:          /number-:page-:slug
  param:        { module: store, action: franchise, page: 1 }
  options:      { suffix: .html, segment_separators: [ /,- ] }
  requirements:
    page: \d+
    slug: "[a-zA-Z0-9\-]+"
```

Answer (score 1):

I tested that case more and more
You can't use more than one separator except `/`

Example

worked "/test-:test"  -> one separator 
not worked "/test-:test-:test" more than one
worked "/test/:test/:test" more than one but "/"

hope this information helpful
Thanks..